# In TypeScript, create object of same class having constructor of http

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

```
 export class FloorPlanComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
      constructor();
      constructor(public _baseComponentService?: BaseComponentService,
                  public _internalZoneService?: InternalZoneService,
                  public routeParams?: ActivatedRoute,
                  public internalAssetService?: InternalAssetService,
                  public slimLoadingBarService?: SlimLoadingBarService,
                  private errorLoggerService?: ErrorLoggerService
                 ) {
                     if (this._baseComponentService != null) {
                           this._baseComponentService.SetPageTitle("Zones - Internal");
                   }
      this.imgDelZone = parentElement.append("image")
        .attr("id", "delZone" + newId)
        .attr("idCounter", newId)
        .attr("r", "NaN")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .attr("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x + (shapeWidth - 22); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + 1; })
        .attr("style", "opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1;")
        .attr("xlink:href", "../app/assets/images/Remove_Delete-22.png")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
        .attr("transform", " ")
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("cursor", "pointer").on("click", function () {
            var comp = new FloorPlanComponent();
            comp.promptDeleteZone(this);
        });
}
```

Inside "click" function, I want to use this to refer my class. But it's referring this as a window object. To resolve this issue, I created a object of class with the help of parameterless constructor. But according to this, I'm unable to get any service. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use arrow function:

```
  attr("cursor", "pointer").on("click", () => {
    ...
  });
```

Arrow functions capture the `this` where the function is created so `this` will point to FloorPlanComponent instance.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for quick reply. I have one more scenario where I'm stuck. See below code.  drag: any = d3.drag().on("drag", this.dragmove);  in dragmove(d) function, I want this as a floorplancomponent as well as get this object of selected drag item. How is it possible.

Comment: You could just save pointer to `this` in local variable and use closure to access it:
`let self = this;
drag: any = d3.drag().on("drag", function() {
  let dragItem = this;
  self.dragmove(dragItem);
});`

Comment: it's not working. I used self:any=this; (in the class root level). Inside the function, self still refer to window object.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.attr("cursor", "pointer").on("click", this.onClicked.bind(this));

.............
onClicked() {
    var comp = new FloorPlanComponent();
    comp.promptDeleteZone(this);
}
```

Comment: I used the same but with this approach I'm unable to use my services. it's showing as undefined.

Comment: You can inject your service from constructor, can't you?